# Archivo adjunto invalido dbmail

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos

Estoy tratando de enviar un email con un archivo adjunto a través de SQL Server de forma local desde mi pc, ya tengo la configuración y hace envíos, el problema es que cuando trato de enviar un archivo adjunto que esta dentro de una carpeta me genera un error

> Attachment file C:\log\log_AlertaError.txt is invalid.

ya le he dado los permisos del usuario SQL a la carpeta log, pero aun así me sigue generando ese error, no se si estoy dando bien los permisos o me hace falta algo ya que no adjunta mi archivo.

así hago el envió del email con el archivo adjunto

```html
USE msdb
EXEC sp_send_dbmail 
@profile_name = 'Pruebas Aplicaciones',
@recipients = 'micorreo@micorreo.com.mx',
@subject='Prueba archivo adjunto',
@body='Un archivo ha sido incluido en este email',    
@file_attachments='C:\log\log_AlertaError.txt'
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]